# RAILS Prism gem only highlights codesample from direct URL or when refreshing page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prismjs

I am using the prism gem and it highlights great but only from a direct URL or after refreshing the page. It does not highlight if navigating from the home page.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="themes/prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="prism.js"></script>
    <title><%= yield(:page_title) %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

  </head>

  <body>

    <%= render "layouts/navbar" %>
    <div class="container <%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">
    <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As an update, it appears that when I go to the direct URL of the page it loads fine. It's only when I navigate there from the home page.

Comment: using `turbolinks`?

Comment: @RaviMariya yes, using turbolinks

Comment: can you show your code? so it will help others to fix the problem

Comment: @RaviMariya any insight?

Comment: Can you share JavaScript code, how are you calling it from view

Comment: @RaviMariya it is called in the above code in the script tag. The js code for prism is several hundred lines long.

Comment: Well might be not loading because of turbolinks, if you want to check, can you add method: :get, in link_to and check

Comment: No luck with that, there is a prism.scss file as well. Yeah, idk what can be the issue.